# Customize the cancel_comment_reply_link WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

As the title suggests, I want to modify or customize the `cancel_comment_reply_link` without editing the `/wp-includes/comment-template.php`.

The code in `comment-template.php` looks like this:

```
<h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">
   <?php comment_form_title( $args['title_reply'], $args['title_reply_to'] ); ?>
        <small>
            <?php cancel_comment_reply_link( $args['cancel_reply_link'] ); ?>
       </small>
</h3>
```

Basically, I want to get the `cancel_comment_reply_link` out of the `<h3>` and `<small>`-Tags into a `<div>` container but I really don't know how to achieve this without touching `comment-template.php`.

Is there a solution to include into my theme's `functions.php`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the complete `comment_form` function into my `functions.php`, renamed it, modified it and included the new function instead of the old one.